# Adjust Brightness for qvideowidget inserted into the QGraphicsscene and QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

I am playing video using the Qgrpahicsscene, QgraphicsView, qvideowidget

```
videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;

QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;

QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(scene);

scene->addWidget(videoWidget);
```

the video playing correctly, what i need is when i adjust brightness in videowidget it is not reflecting and i have checked the videowidget brightness level it is setting.
please share some ideas,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve pretty much all kinds of effects and corrections with the use of shaders, brightness in particular is a very simple fragment shader, just multiply each pixel's luminosity by a real multiplier. With QML you even have the ready to use shader effects as well as the QML video effects example.

[Brightness/Contrast](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qml-qtgraphicaleffects1-brightnesscontrast.html)

[All ready to use effects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qmlmodule-qtgraphicaleffects1-qtgraphicaleffects-1-0.html)

[QML video effects example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/video-qmlvideofx.html)

You could use shaders even with widgets if you go for a `QGLWidget` base widget and still get the great performance.

Answer (score 3):

Update the scene after the change of brightness. Like this:

```
videoWidget->setBrightness(bright);
scene->update(scene->sceneRect());
```